# Linksys WRT54G Won't Allow PPPoE

Tags: wireless-router

I'm doing a router for a customer with DSL.  However, this modem won't allow me to change it to PPPoE on the Internet Connection Type.  It just keeps defaulting to DHCP... any ideas?  I've tried hooking up DSL equipment to it, resetting it to factory defaults.

Comment: Have you verfiied, the manual, that a PPPoE option should even be offered, you might be trying to do something the router simply doesn't support.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have.

Comment: You have verified your running the current revision of the hardware?  Have you considered loading a third-party firmware, specifically a version, you have more control over?

Answer (score 0):

If the Linksys device will not hold the settings after you click Save (you need to configure the PPPoE settings first - see the image below) you most likely have corrupted firmware.

I would recommend downloading a new firmware image from Linksys, flashing the device and trying again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this exact same issue on my own WRT54G. My issue was directly related to the browser. (I was using Chrome)

Switching to Internet Explorer solved my problem.